# combinatorics method difference

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say you give a number between 0 and 20 to 30 people (one number to each person and repetition is allowed)

how many such distributions are there? => 21^30

## But what if you know that there is surely one person that gets the number 5?

21^30 - 20^30 (the case when no one has 5)

but why is the above solution different then doing this:
you choose the person that gets a 5:

(30 nCr 1)

you multiply it by the rest
21^29
?

Comment: That would be the number of ways of giving a single *golden five* to one person and ordinary numbers to other persons including possibly a regular ordinary five to some of these other persons.  The way you propose makes it matter which of the people specifically among all those who got fives got the *golden five*...

Comment: your question is not clear... how many number can a person take ? ıs repetition allowed ? and please use mathjax

Comment: Take your logic and apply it to the problem "*say you give a number between 5 and 5 to 30 people.*"  There is precisely one outcome... where they all got fives.  Now... "*what if you know that there is surely (at least) one person that gets the number 5?*"  According to your logic $\binom{30}{1}\cdot 1^{29}$...

Comment: your problem is about understanding the question , it is not said that there is exactly one person who takes $5$ , it is said that there is at least one person who takes $5$ , so all distribution - no one takes $5$

Comment: @Bulbasaur that's why I have 21^29 and not 20^29

Comment: If you insist on approach directly rather than indirectly, break into cases based on the number of people who got a five, choose who all of them are simultaneously (*thus avoiding making the first chosen "special" compared to the others*), and then give *non-fives* to everyone else.  $\binom{30}{1}20^{29}+\binom{30}{2}20^{28}+\binom{30}{3}20^{27}+\dots$ which should immediately remind you of the binomial theorem expansion of $(1+20)^{30}$, just missing the first term.  A bit of algebra shows that the direct answer is of course equal to the indirect answer of $21^{30}-20^{30}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I understand it now, thank you!

Comment: For an alternate direct approach, rather than breaking into cases based on the total number of fives given out, instead break into cases based on the position of the first five in the line of people.  This gives $1\cdot 21^{29}+20\cdot1\cdot 21^{28}+20^2\cdot 1\cdot 21^{27}+20^3\cdot 1\cdot 21^{26}+\dots+20^{29}\cdot 1$ which after dividing everything by $21^{29}$ should remind you of a geometric series, $1+\frac{20}{21}+(\frac{20}{21})^2+(\frac{20}{21})^3+\dots+(\frac{20}{21})^{29}$ and you can use what you know of geometric sums to again get the same result.